# Using mailboxer gem with heroku --cedar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sqlite, heroku

I want to use the mailboxer gem - https://github.com/ging/mailboxer
But i noticed that The Ruby Toolbox has listed sqlite3-ruby as one of the dependencies for this gem. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/projects/mailboxer

My demo app is deployed on Heroku -- cedar and this does not go well with sqlite3 (from my previous experience where I had to migrate from sqlite3 to postgresql)

So my question: Can I use the mailboxer gem together with Heroku?

I had thought of a couple of workarounds but had not tested them:

1. custom remove the dependency on sqlite3 - but i have no idea how this would affect the mailboxer gem
2. install the gem anyway and hope for the best. :)

So if anyone have used this gem successfully with Heroku on cedar(for rails 3.1) do let me know. Sorry if this question is a noob question. thank youuu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have no problem related with this dependency. As you can see in Rubygems https://rubygems.org/gems/mailboxer, sqlite3-ruby dependency is just for development.

So install the gem and hope for the best!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just installed it and hope for the best quite some time ago. Next time when I'm checking on dependencies I will be sure to check the environment it was specified for. Thanks again.